# Random Class not working on Android 4.1+

Tags: java, android, random

This is the code I am using to generate a random set of numbers:

```
...
        public boolean placeTreasure()  {
            randomGen = new Random();
            int[] treasureLoc = {0, 0};

            while (treasureLoc[0] < 2 || treasureLoc[1] < 2)    {
                treasureLoc[0] = randomGen.nextInt(rows - 2);
                treasureLoc[1] = randomGen.nextInt(columns - 2);
                System.out.println("" + treasureLoc[0] + ", " + treasureLoc[1]);
            }
            maze[treasureLoc[0]][treasureLoc[1]] = '*';

            return true;
        }
...
```

The funny thing is that it works just fine on earlier versions of Android. As far as I know, anything above 4.1 does not run this properly. It constantly gives me pairs of `0, 0`. This leads me to believe that either 4.1+ does not support the random class, or something else weird is going on with my implementation. This method works just fine on earlier versions though, so I'm not sure what's going on.

If anyone has suggestions on alternate implementations of this (I need to generate random integers between `2` and `rows` or `columns`).

Comment: What are the values of rows and columns when this code is called? Are you printing them out to be sure? Why re-create a Random object inside of the method rather than simply creating it once? Why have the while loop? Why not simply get `randomGen.nextInt(rows - 2) + 2` and similarly for the other number?

Comment: Don't you want to add `2` to each, instead of entering a loop which retries until it finds random numbers between `0` and `rows-2`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels rows and columns can be anything. Yes I am printing them out to be sure. I am not recreating a Random object, I am only doing this once. Good idea. But that still doesn't solve the problem of the Random class not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If anyone has suggestions on alternate implementations of this (I need to generate random integers between 2 and rows or columns).

Yes, very simply:

```
int randomRow = randomGen.nextInt(rows - 2) + 2;
int randomCol = randomGen.nextInt(columns - 2) + 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem that the Random class does not work persists. It continuously returns 0. Great suggestion on getting rid of the loop though, stupid me. If you can solve my real problem, then that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @capcom: I am 99.9999% sure that the bug is in your code and not in Android's implementation of Random. You're not showing us enough for us to be able to solve it, but if you do some more studious debugging, I'll bet you'll find it.

Comment: I think you are right! I think I'm giving the Random generator a parameter of 1. How silly of me. Thank you so much!

Comment: @capcom: you're welcome and glad you found the bug! Please note that I wasn't insulting you with my comment above. I've found that whenever I've thought that the error was due to Java, 99.9999% of the time I was wrong and the error was in my understanding of Java. I figured your odds were similar.

Comment: I would never perceive someone's help insulting in any way. I'm an amateur programmer, and I will only get better when I encounter scenarios like this one. It's very nice to know that people like you are willing to spend their time to help others. Thanks again. I fixed the problem in the code, and all is ok.